# Check if label, position in one dataframe fall in label, range of second dataframe of different lengths pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes. The first contains a label and a start and a stop column, and the second contains a label and a position. The second dataframe is longer than the first.

I want to select rows in the second dataframe that fall within any of the ranges in the first dataframe.

Here is a MCVE. The `interval_df` is the one containing the intervals I want to look inside, the `check_df` has the label + position I want to search for, and `result_df` is what I expect the final output to be. Uncomment any print statement to see:

```
import pandas as pd

interval_df = pd.DataFrame({'Chr': [1,1,2,2,3,3], 'Pos1': [1,100,1,60,80,200], 'Pos2': [10,150,50,70,90,210]})
#print(interval_df)
check_df = pd.DataFrame({'Chr': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3], 'Pos':[8,9,11,110,200,45,55,10,50,80,85,200]})
#print(check_df)
result_df = pd.DataFrame({'Chr': [1,1,1,2,3,3,3], 'Pos':[8,9,110,45,80,85,200]})
#print(result_df)

# create ranges in the first df as a unique column
interval_df['interval'] = interval_df.apply(lambda x: range(x['Pos1'], x['Pos2']+1), axis=1)

# find the positions in check_df that have the same label and a position that is in the range in interval_df
output = check_df.loc[(check_df['Chr'] == interval_df['Chr']) & (check_df['Pos'] in interval_df['interval'])]
```

But here is the error I get:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do `check_df['Chr'] == interval_df['Chr']` because they have different length. Plus, `(check_df['Pos'] in interval_df['interval'])` would fail for several reasons:

1. you can't do `series in list_like`, but rather `series.isin(list_like)`;
2. even then `series.isin(list_like)` would check if each element of the `series` is in the `list_like`, however, in your case `interval_df['interval']` is a series of ranges, so `8` in `check_df['Pos']` would not be equal to `range(1,10)` in `interval_df['interval']`.

---

All that said, you can perform a cross merge and query:

```
(check_df.merge(interval_df, on='Chr', how='left')
         .query('Pos1<=Pos<=Pos2')
         [check_df.columns]
)
```

Output:

```
    Chr  Pos
0     1    8
2     1    9
7     1  110
10    2   45
18    3   80
20    3   85
23    3  200
```

Comment: I am running this now, my data is obviously a bit bigger than what I posted and the join has taken ~40G :D.

Comment: One should never do a cross merge on `40G` data :D

Comment: The filesize of input is ~800Mb but the crossmerge took 128G of memory! But it did work. Thanks

Comment: I processed it in chunks and brought the memory way down at the cost of speed. Thanks again!